# PHP built in webserver error reporting

Tags: php

I'm using the built in PHP server and I'd like to suppress the strict warnings. In my php.ini file i have:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

...but it is still printing strict and deprecated notices. I verified that I was editing the correct ini file by checking a page with phpinfo().

In [the built in webserver documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), there is no mention of special error reporting rules.

I have also tried this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
print "changed stuff";
```

"changed stuff" is printed, along with strict and deprecated notices.

What do I need to do to suppress these errors in the PHP built in webserver? (Can this be done?)

Comment: Ack! Someone had the right answer but then deleted it!

Comment: I guess he's gone. I searched through my code (it's a very old codebase) and found several instances where the error reporting was manually set. Once i removed those it worked. *check your files for error_reporting calls*

Comment: You can answer your own question. Your comment helped me too. Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through my code (it's a very old codebase) and found several instances where the error reporting was manually set. Once i removed those it worked.

Check your files for `error_reporting` calls

Answer (score 1):

Try changing like this [Reports all errors except STRICT ]

**Through Code**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

**Through PHP.ini**

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT
```